# Installed Anaconda for python 2 and 3. Can't run 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I installed both versions of Anaconda for Python 2 and 3.

I added path.

I use Anaconda prompt.

```
python program.py
```

It assumes I am using Python 3. For example, it can't understand:

```
print "hello!"
```

I tried:

```
py program.py
py -2 program.py
```

But they didn't work. How can I run a Python 2 program?

If I type:

```
python
```

in the Acaconda prompt, then it says:

```
python 3.5.1. Anaconda 2.4.1
```

So the prompt is assuming I am using Python 3.

But I have programs written in Python 2 AND programs written in Python 3.

I want to switch between the two smoothly. How should I do this?

Comment: Ah...`python2 program.py`?

Comment: @KevinGuan It didn't work.. maybe that is a solution to another distribution than anaconda?

Comment: So, try to find the real path of your `python` command via `which python`. And then try `ls <path>/python*` and check the output.

Comment: @KevinGuan  Thank you. I changed my question.

Answer (score 9):

The simples solution is to create an environment for Python 2:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

This will take a few seconds and will show you a ling list of packages it is going to install. Just press enter and wait.

Once finished activate your new environment.

On Windows:

```
activate py27
```

On other platforms:

```
source activate py27
```

The prompt should change to `(py27)`. Now you use Python 2.7.

Deactivate with:

```
deactivate
```

Now you are back to Python 3. You can run both versions in two terminal windows at the same time. You can create environments for other Python versions:

```
conda create -n py34 python=3.4 anaconda
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 anaconda
```

If you don't want the full Anaconda installation in an environment, create one with all packages:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.5
source activate myenv
```

and install what you need. For example:

```
conda install numpy pytables sympy
```

You can define a `bash` function in your `.profile` or `.bashrc`:

```
py27() {
exec &>/dev/null
source activate py27
exec &>/dev/tty
python $*
exec &>/dev/null
source deactivate
exec &>/dev/tty
}
```

Now you can run your program with Python 27, provided you created an environment with this name using Python 2.7:

```
py27 myscript.py
```

You can generalize further an create a command for Python 2.6, 2,7, 3.3, 3.4, and 3.5:

```
pyxx() {
exec &>/dev/null
source activate $1
exec &>/dev/tty
python ${*:2}
exec &>/dev/null
source deactivate
exec &>/dev/tty
}


py26()
{
    pyxx py26 $*
}

py27()
{
    pyxx py27 $*
}

py33()
{
    pyxx py33 $*
}

py34()
{
    pyxx py34 $*
}

py35()
{
    pyxx py35 $*
}
```

This assumes you already created environments with the according names and Python versions.

Comment: Thank you very much! But if I do this, can I use both python 2 and 3? Before installing python via Anaconda, I was using another distribution and I could use python 2 by typing "python xxx.py" and python 3 by typing "py -3 xxx.py"   So depending on the language the program was written, I could switch back and forth "on the prompt". Can I do this?

Comment: Yes you can. In fact you can create as many environments as you like for Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3., 3.4, and 3.5.

Comment: " You can run both versions in two terminal windows at the same time." This means I have to open two terminals, right? But how can I run both versions of python programs in one terminal window? e.g. when I run python 3 program, I would type "py3 xxx.py" and when I run python 2 program I would type "py2 xxx.py"

Comment: It seems your solution allows me to change the environment from 2 to 3 and vice versa. That's good.. but can't I simply add "-3" when I type "py -3 xxx.py" when I run the program? That was what I did before installing Anaconda. So I thought there must be a way to do this for Anaconda..